# Do you get credit for the Nexus Challenge quests if you add somebody on your team as a friend during draft?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

If you're playing draft (e.g. Hero League) do you get credit toward the Nexus Challenge quests (play 15/30 games with a friend) if you and one of your teammates add each other as friends during the draft phase or do you have to be friends in the same party before entering the queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this yesterday and yes it does count toward the quests if you add one or more of your teammates as a friend during the draft. It definitely makes it a lot easier to complete the quests.